# AVPlayerItem doesn't play video even its status is `readyToPlay` and `isPlaybackLikelyToKeepUp` is true

Tags: ios, avplayer, avplayeritem

I'm playing live video with `AVPlayer` and `AVPlayerItem`. I'm observing `AVPlayerItem`'s `status`, `isPlaybackLikelyToKeepUp`, and `AVPlayerItemPlaybackStalled`. I'm also observing `AVPlayer`'s `rate`.

While I'm testing I found really weird thing happened.

While `AVPlayer` plays video normally(`AVPlayerItem.status == readyToPlay` and `AVPlayerItem.isPlaybackLikelyToKeepUp == true`), if I press home button, the `AVPlayer.rate` becomes `0.0`. It means player stopped playing.

When app got back to foreground and I press play button, it is still `AVPlayerItem.status == readyToPlay` and `AVPlayerItem.isPlaybackLikelyToKeepUp == true` but paused and after a while it starts to play.

What I want is to know the player is paused or playing. In this case, even player is not playing video, the status indicates it is playing. (`AVPlayerItem.status == readyToPlay`, `AVPlayerItem.isPlaybackLikelyToKeepUp == true`, `AVPlayer.rate == 1.0`)

I checked `AVPlayerItem`'s `loadedTimeRanges` and `item.loadedTimeRanges.first` is not nil(loadedTimeRanges has only one item) and its `start` and `duration` are not 0.

What should I check?

*I'm adding little more.*

This symptom only happens with streaming(m3u8) not with vod(mp4).

So I guess it is a problem of buffered data. While player is playing, buffer has data to play and the data is still valid. After app goes background and back to foreground, player's buffer still has data so `isPlaybackLikelyToKeepUp == true`, `AVPlayerItem.status == readyToPlay`. However when I try to play, `AVPlayer` flushes buffer because it is old.

It looks like the only way so far is create new `AVPlayerItem` and set when app is back to foreground.

What is the exact problem I'm encountering and want to know how to avoid it.

This is the repo I'm working on.

https://github.com/trick14/SLPlayer

The upper one is live and bottom one is VOD. After loading is done, play and go background and foreground couple times. And if you try to play, all status looks normal but player is stalled.

Comment: What is the nature of not liking the video (any errors or warnings in the console)? What file format is the video? Is it local (same device) or remote?

Comment: @AndreM no error/warning in the console. I tested with m8u and mp4 in remote server.

Comment: could you provide a short code snippet? Is this is the simulator or actual device and if so which device?

Comment: I tested with Simulator(iOS10/iPhone5s) and device(iOS10.1.1/iPhone6s+).

Comment: Can you show some code or link to a project that reproduces the problem?

Comment: both seem to work if you give them time to buffer

Comment: @RhythmicFistman I'm not saying it doesn't work. I want to know how to figure out it is loading status even AVPlayerItem.status is readyToPlay and isPlaybackLikelyToKeepUp is true.

Comment: I could reproduce the issue, but have no answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar experience long time ago.
At that time, I've stored the status of playing and the playback location when user press home button.
When return to the foreground, I used the stored information to restore or play the location.

I hope you were helpful.